# Is air intake pulling in humid air a concern ?

Tags: ventilation

We've got a server room in a project where we dont have AC.

Ive got a room which we plan to setup as per the rough diagram here, which details the air intake vent and the air extract fan / vent.

The rack room has 3 external walls.

Would there be any issues regarding humidity / humid air being pulled in from outside when its raining ?

[image: rough diagram of rack room]

Comment: depends how often it rains. ....  just paint the room with paint that is designed for bathrooms and you should be ok.

Comment: You may worry about condensation in the server room if the air is humid and temperatures drop. A dehumidifier would help, but may not be necessary if you have good enough airflow.